# Create ssh tunnel on startup

Tags: raspbian, ssh, cron

I have looked at various questions but none seems to work...

I have a remote Pi that for various reasons tends to lose power occasionally and then boot back up. I don't have physical access to this thing very often so I set up an ssh tunnel to access it remotely. I need this tunnel to start when the Pi reboots so that I can always have access, even if the power goes in and out.

I have the following script `create_tunnel.sh` running in a cronjob (user and hostname removed obviously):

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -N -R 4445:localhost:22 user@hostname &
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Tunnel to host created successfully"
else
    echo "An error occurred creating a tunnel to host. RC was $?"
fi
```

And here is the crontab:

```
@reboot /usr/local/sbin/create_tunnel.sh > /usr/local/sbin/tunnel.log
```

When I reboot manually, I can see in `tunnel.log` that the job ran:

```
Tue  4 Apr 13:34:27 EDT 2017
Tunnel to host created successfully
```

But the tunnel does not exist. And when I go to run the command manually, after the Pi has booted, the tunnel comes up fine and I can connect to it without any hassle. What's going on? Is the tunnel getting created and then later destroyed somehow?

Comment: I have used *autossh* for this purpose in the past. It has a number of convenience features that might make it simpler than rolling your own with bare *ssh*, including keepalives and reestablishing dropped connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -N -R 4445:localhost:22 user@hostname &
```

You start the process in the background, which is always successful regardless the result. You should use `-f` switch instead, which will make the process go to background just after the connection and port forwarding is established (or failed):

```
/usr/bin/ssh -f -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -N -R 4445:localhost:22 user@hostname
```

Comment: Thanks! This didn't fix the problem but it did reveal that the tunnel was not being created properly by showing the correct result in the log file.